# Automated testing in virtual machines using Hyper-V

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v, windows-10, automation

I was tasked to automate our department's testing process.
To do the testing I first have to install a setup of our application on the host system and run another application, the tester, afterwards.
The tester application uses an `ActiveX` control to control the previously installed application. In order to run the tester application I need a graphical interface, so I can't run the tests headless.

To automate the process I thought about using `Hyper-V` and a `Powershell` script to automatically deploy clean `Windows VMs`, install the setup, run the tester application and destroy the `VM` afterwards.

The deployment process works just fine but now comes the tricky part of actually running the tester application without manually interacting with the `VM`.
Initially I thought that I could remote control the `VM` via `Powershell` and just execute the tester application that in turn opens up its GUI and does the testing.

Unfortunately I was wrong. I googled around for a bit but couldn't really find anything so far that worked.

My question is now if my approach is feasible and if it is how I possibly solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is set an auto-logon in the VM with a generic user for your tests, and create an executable (or a script) that you would add in one of the auto-start location of Windows `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` for example.

This little program will contact a web service by passing the VM name as a parameter in the request, then, the web service will output a list of tasks, or a command to start in your VM.

Then you can create a management tool to create the relationship between the VMs and the "tasks".

If you don't want to create a webservice, you can simply put text files or PowerShell scripts in a file share (the file name would be the VM name for example) and you just have to start/read the corresponding file when the VM starts.

Comment: Oh never thought about auto start :) A webservice is not needed in the first place but is planned for a future expansion of the system. Thanks a lot, will try this approach in the next days